# strlen (php) doesnt give right result

Tags: strlen

i try simple lenght check with php.Posted value is 12/26, The code is :

```
            echo "length:" . strlen($this->request->post["expiration"]);
    
            if (strlen($this->request->post["expiration"]==5)){
                    echo "correct";
            }else{
                    echo "wrong";
            
            }
        exit;
```

result is:

```
length:5 wrong
```

Would you please what is my mistake?

Answer (score 0):

Pay attention to this line: `if (strlen($this->request->post["expiration"]==5))`.
You're basically trying to use strlen on the entire expression. Try this one instead: `if (strlen($this->request->post["expiration"])==5)`

Comment: Thank you very much! 
$a= $this->request->post["expiration"];
and then strlen($a) gave the correct answer. Thank you for your time. Be safe.

Answer (score 0):

```
/* Please see the code if it works */

<?php
        echo "length:" . strlen($this->request->post["expiration"]);
        $a= strlen($this->request->post["expiration"]);
            if ($a==5))
            {
                    echo "correct";
            }else
            {
                    echo "wrong";
            
            }
        exit;
     ?>
```

Comment: Yes , this one worked , my mistake :/   Thank you very much !